# set custom wrap column

Tags: terminal, terminal-emulator, wrap

```
OS: SLES12,
terminal emulator: mate 1.22.1,
shell: tcsh
$TERM: xterm-256color
```

I want to set the line wrapping in the terminal so that any text that appears on the terminal (stdout or otherwise) wraps a few columns left to the edge.

I always work with full-screen terminal (which I think is defined as width = 80) so I don't mind if that behavior breaks when the terminal is not in full screen.

I know of the command "fold" but I don't know how to apply it to the entirety of the terminal.

If there's a way to apply it to only stdout then I can take it as a compromise.

Thanks

Comment: this is usually terminal dependent. eg: putty, xterm, urxvt, etc all have their own methods for setting line wrapping... I'd assume terminal emulator in Mate is using vte3, given that mate is basically gnome-built... not sure about vte3, but i don't think it supports what you are trying to do.

Comment: When I run "echo $TERM" I receive "xterm-256color".

Does this mean what I think it means? If it does, is it possible in xterm?

Comment: Also, I can request IT to install another terminal emulator if it's possible/required.

Comment: Do you need those character cells beyond column 80 for _anything_? If no, you can try to significantly increase the terminal's border/padding to occupy that space, see e.g. https://superuser.com/a/1164998/278816.